# the image does not appear in web browser using rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with my app in rails . i am creating a simple blog in rails. but images not loaded on browser . i have put images on app/assets/images.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please add the view where you use the images.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

If you put file on assets folder, you should using [pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), like:

```
<%= image_tag 'profile.png' %>
```

Or if all you want is the path to image without tag:

```
<%= asset_path 'profile.png' %>
```

Moreover, for using path without pipeline like `host/img/profile.png`, you should put images on:
`/public/img/profile.png`